# How to hit the Next button from Python using Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation

I am trying to work with the following site using Python.
Please advise how can I hit the Next button:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,40)

driver.get('https://www.okcupid.com/login')

driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();',wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username'))))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username'))).send_keys("abc")

driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();',wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username'))))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'password'))).send_keys("123")

# Find login button
login_button = driver.find_element_by_name('Next')
# Click login
login_button.click()
```

But got an error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="Next"]"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name is a an attribute on a webelement. The next button has no Name attribute.

You can try this xpath:

> //input[@value='Next']

```
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Next"]')
```